# The number of all possible different keys or passwords

Tags: password-encryption

Today I took encryption exam and the professor asked us this following question.
In my point of view I wrote the solution as the follow: 2^46*10^6 + 2^46*10^7+2^46*10^8
Is that correct ? Since other students found this solution correct : 46*10^6 + 46*10^7+46*10^8

Can anyone give his/her opinion and how/why which answer is correct ?
Thanks in advance.

Question is : If all Latin alphabets, all numbers, and 10 special characters are implemented in the generation of keys for a cryptosystem or passwords of lengths between 6 and 8 characters, calculate.​
(a) The number of all possible different keys or passwords.

Comment: Are lower case and upper case letters not included?

Comment: No, it doesn't mind . Just only 26 cases for alphabetical with 10 cases for numbers and 10 special char.

Answer (score 1):

If we have 26 letters, 10 digits and 10 special characters, the total is an alphabet of 46 symbols. A password is any possible word where one of those symbols appears in a particular position. I also assume that any symbol can be used more than once.

Now, if I fix the length to 6 symbols, I can choose one out of 46 symbols for the first character of the password, another one for the second, and so on. That means I'll have 46 possible symbols in position 1, 46 in position 2, ..., 46 possible symbols in position 6. The number of total passwords of length 6 is 46*46*46*46*46*46 = 46<sup>6</sup>.

So, the number of total possible passwords is: 46<sup>6</sup>+46<sup>7</sup>+46<sup>8</sup>.